# .prevUntil(".class:nth-child("+(index + 1)+") Does not appear to work correctly in Chrome, any ideas on how I can get it to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hp7Cz/25/

```
$('.moveDownLink').click(function() {

var $thisQuestion = $(this).parent();
var originalIndex = $thisQuestion.index();    
var $textField = $(this).next();
var fieldVal = parseInt($textField.val());


        var $target = $('.question:eq('+(fieldVal - 1)+')');
        var $newElement = $thisQuestion.clone().insertAfter($target);
        $newElement.prevUntil(".question:nth-child("+ (originalIndex + 1)  +")").each(function() {
            var $tField = $(this).find('input');
            var val = parseInt($tField.val());
            $tField.attr('value',(val - 1));
        });

        $thisQuestion.detach();




});​
```

The example code is to only handle moving questions down i.e from position 1 to 4 etc.
Oddly if moving question 1 to 4th place first it will work in Chrome. But moving anything higher down i.e Question 2 to 3rd place will fail as the .prevUntil() will not stop at the specified element in the selector and continue enumerating all elements irrespective of index specified in the nth-child filter.

In IE and FireFox it all works, correctly ordering each time: 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone your object you lose the event listener. And it does not work in FF or IE for me.

Try using .on() instead, http://jsfiddle.net/hp7Cz/30/

```
$('#container').on("click", ".moveDownLink", function() {}
```